# GXT text format in Tooltip in Grid

Tags: java, tooltip, gxt

I have a string stored in DB / `textarea`.
If i try `System.out.println(text);
The output is:

```
Test text
it is good

i am a line after a line break actually.

http://aaaaaaaaa.bbbbbbbbb.cccccccccc.ddddddddd.com/testtesttesttest

Unix path :
/test/home/user/tester/
```

Then i tried to use the function `panel.getGrid().setTooltip(text);`

The text in the tooltip showing as :

```
Test text it is good i am line after a line break
actually.
http://aaaaaaaaa.bbbbbbbbb.cccccccccc.ddddddddd.com/testtesttesttest Unix
path : /test/home/user/tester/
```

It is not the format i want, how to showing the tooltip with right format?

I am using `void com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component.setToolTip(String text)` and the version is 2.4.0 or 2.3.0

********Update**********

I found that `System.err.println(view.getGrid().getToopTip().getHtml());`
is showing the correct HTML format, how to make the Tooltips showing this format?

Answer (score 0):

I think tooltips use html.  Are you using html line breaks `<br>`?

Comment: What do you mean there's no way to use html coding?  If it has different line breaks then whenever you are creating the tooltip do `tooltipString.replaceAll("whatever line break the string has", "<br>")`.  Just tested adding `<br>` to a tooltip string and it definitely does a line break.